# Using library(element).function() or library.function() constructions in Javascript lib

Tags: javascript, oop, construction

We have Javascript library:

```js
(function (global, factory) {
  factory(global);
}(window , function() {
  var MyLib = function(elem) {
    return new MyLib.foo.init(elem);
  }
  MyLib.foo = {
    init: function(elem) {
      elem = typeof elem == 'string' ? window.document.getElementById(elem) : elem;
      this[0] = elem;
      return this;
    },
  
    test1: function() { // (1)
      window.console.log('test1 ' + this[0].nodeName);
      this[0].innerHTML = this[0].nodeName;
    },
  };

  MyLib.foo.init.prototype = MyLib.foo;
  MyLib.test2 = function() { // (2)
    window.console.log('test2');
  }

  window.MyLib = window.ml = MyLib;
}));

function outerFunc(elem) {
  ml(elem).test1();
  ml.test2();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>   
  <div onclick="outerFunc(this)">button</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When should we create functions like (1) and when like (2)?
Of course, if it needs to get an element, we would **always** use ***(1)***, like MyLib().myFunc(), am I right?
And for all situations, where an element is not affected, we should create ***(2)*** ,like MyLib.myFunc()?
May be we miss something with variables' protection?

Comment: Toss of a coin? You're comparing creating properties as an object literal vs assignment, use whatever suits. Whether you need to get an element or not is irrelevant. BTW, don't pass *window* to *global*, pass *this* as it's the only reference you **know** can't be altered. I fail to see any similarity with features of jQuery that are in any way unique to jQuery.

Comment: TY! Corrected text and thought about global.